# Mac で Python3 IDLE を使った場合に日本語を入力する方法

Tags: python, python3

Python3で、＃のあとに日本語を使いたいです。方法をわかりやすく教えてください。[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: 日本語を使うと、どうなりますか？ もしかすると、日本語の入力自体が出来ない状態なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

IDLEのShellに

> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
>   Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

と出ていませんか??

まさに書いてある通り、macOS付属の8.5.9というバージョンのTcl/Tkは不安定で、深刻なバグが存在します("the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 still has serious bugs" via http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ )。

日本語が入力できないという現象も報告されていますし、8.5.11以降で解消されたという報告をしている人もいます。
私自身も、現時点で最新の ActiveTcl で日本語が入力できることは確認しています。

リンク先から ActiveTcl をダウンロード/インストールして、PythonもmacOS付属のものではなくて、別のものを使いましょう。
もしすでにmacOS付属のものではないPythonを使っているなら、新しくインストールしたTcl/Tkを見にいく様に、再コンパイルもしくは再インストールしましょう。

Comment: *日本語が入力できることは確認しています。*: ActiveTcl 8.5.18 をインストールしましたが変換前の文字が表示されないって問題をこちらでは確認してます。

Answer (score 1):

私は2018年4月現在、Sierra と High Sierra を利用していますが、macOS付属のPythonのTkinter で、日本語入力が出来ないことを把握しています。

またActiveTcl の Tkでも、変換途中のテキストが見えないことも知っています。
（入力確定したら表示されるので入力できない訳では無い）

他のエディタ入力した日本語テキストを Copy/Paste すれば入力できますが、残念ながら使い勝手は良くありません。

この事象はpythonに限らず、同じTkを利用している Ruby や Rでも同様に発生しています。
（Tcl/Tkの問題ですから）

Answer (score 0):

スクリプトのエンコーディング(文字コード)を
一行目または二行目に

```
# coding: エンコーディング名
# coding=エンコーディング名
```

のどちらかので形式で書きます。
（正確には[リンク先](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding)で書かれているパターンにマッチする形式）

例えば、UTF-8 の場合、

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

のように書きます。
これで、スクリプトがUTF-8で書かれていることを理解してくれます。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

と書いているコードを見かけることがあるかもしれませんが、
こうするとエディタであるEmacsもスクリプトのエンコーディングを理解してくれるためです。
指定可能なエンコーディングは[リンク先](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)を参照下さい。

参照：[Defining the Encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding)

Comment: Python3 ではデフォルトで UTF-8 なので、これは必要ないはずです。

Comment: そうですね。単にスクリプトをUTF-8で書きましょうでもいいですけど、環境変数とか使用環境で変わってくるかもと思ったので。

Comment: Mac の IDLE の文字コードは UTF-8 ではないのですか？ もしそうなら、そういった事情を説明しないと、この質問に対する回答にはならないと思います。

Comment: スクリーンショットからはMacのようですが、当面そういった違いが問題になっているのかはよくわかりませんので、一般的な話をしました。（特に現時点で質問がそのように限定されてはないのでまず一般的なところから始めるべきかと思います）私自身は現在MacユーザーではないのでMacの開発環境に関わることとかそこら辺はよくわからんです。